# Trouble with Code Executing After startActivity()

Tags: android

I am creating a quiz app. In the code below, I want the code after `startActivity(intent);` to execute once that Activity has finished. The app in its current state will display the question text and answer buttons. Once the user makes a choice, the next question and corresponding answer buttons will be displayed for a split second before the new activity is launched. What I want is for the app to go straight to the new Activity upon answer selection, and once the new Activity has finished, to display the next question.

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

// helper variable to keep track of the current question
questionCounter++;
if(questionCounter < numGameQuestions)
{
    // displays the next question
    playGame(randQuestionsArr[questionCounter]);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Is it not starting? Try starting the intent using `Activity` context. like: `Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, NewActivity.class);`

Comment: Its very confusing what is happening and what you *want* to happen. After you call `startActivity()`, that `Activity` will start. Could you explain a little better what you *want* to happen and what *is* happening?

Comment: **What is happening**:
In the current activity, I have a TextView to display the question and four Buttons for the answer choices. Once the user clicks a button, the TextView and Buttons will be set, for a split second, to the next question and its corresponding answer choices. Then NewActivity starts.

Comment: **What I want to happen**:
In the current activity, I have a TextView to display the question and four Buttons for the answer choices. Once the user clicks a button, the NewActivity should start. When NewActivity is finished, the app should revert back and display the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Add definition

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
```

2 Replace startActivity() with startActivityForResult();

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE );
```

3 Before finishing your activity in your child activity,call setResult method;

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

4 Add the things your what to do in onActivityResult method in parent activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE ) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: @Jesse make sure you deal with the entire app's chain of activities, e.g. home versus back button, etc. to make sure the behavior is what you expect, i.e., does the back button take you back one question or to the beginning ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`

By calling `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`, you also need to:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_YOU_USED_IN_STARTACTIVITYFORRESULT:
        switch (resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            Log.d(TAG, "Result OK");
            // Your code after "that Activity" is finished.

            break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And then at `that Activity`, you need to:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

to let the calling activity know the result.

Answer (score 0):

use

> finish()

to stop the execution of current [activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) after starting the new intent